# zend : Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_User' not found

Tags: linux, zend-framework, amazon-ec2

I am trying connecting to my model class defined in /application/models named user.php.
Following is how my Bootstrap looks like:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap{
    protected function _initAppAutoload() {
            $autoloader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
                            'namespace' => 'Application',
                            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
                            'resourceTypes' => array(
                                            'model' => array(
                                                            'path' => 'models',
                                                            'namespace' => 'Model',
                                            )
                            )
            ));
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($autoloader);
            return $autoloader;
    }
```

}

Folling is my application.ini

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
```

Following is my IndexController.php

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

private $user_connection;
private $login_status;

public function init() {
    /* Initialize action controller here */
    $this->user_connection = new Application_Model_User();
}

public function indexAction() {

    $sql = "    SELECT *
               FROM USER";
    $this->view->deals = $this->user_connection->select($sql);
}
```

following is my user.php file:

```
class Application_Model_User extends Application_Model_Db_Connection {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function Connection(){
    return $this->getConnection();
}

public function insert($data, $table = 'user'){
   return parent::insert($table, $data);
}

public function select($sql){
    return parent::select($sql);
}
```

}

Strange part is, I am developing on windows and everything runs fine, but when I push the same code to my ec2 linux instance, I get this fatal error.

```
Fatal error:  Class 'Application_Model_User' not found in /var/www/html/dev/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 11
```

I went through many questions on stack overflow and tried most of them, but I am not close to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try renaming `user.php` to `User.php`.

Comment: Thanks Nandkumar- even I thought about the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the above issue, it was due to case sensitivity of linux. I renamed my models with first letter capital and was able to access them in my Controller.

user.php -> User.php

also for adding subfolder to your model you can add following to the bootstrap.

```
protected function _initAppAutoload() {
    $autoloader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'namespace' => 'Application',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
            'resourceTypes' => array(
                    'model' => array(
                            'path' => 'models/',
                            'namespace' => 'Model_',
                    ),
                    'model_db' => array(
                        'path' => 'models/db',
                        'namespace' => 'Model_Db_'
                    )
            )
    ));
```